# How to fetch distinct results based on 1 property in Core Data but still fetch all properties?

Tags: swift, core-data

My goal is to fetch distinct `SearchHistoryItemModel`.

My expected result:

```
[
  {
    id: "1", -> it's a String
    keyword: "abcd", -> it's a String
    timestamp: " time1 " -> it's a Date()
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    keyword: "abcde",
    timestamp: " time2 "
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    keyword: "abcde",
    timestamp: " time3 "
  }
]
```

My actual result:

```
[
  {
    keyword: "abcd"
  },
  {
    keyword: "abcde"
  }
]
```

Example of data in Core Data:

```
[
  {
    id: "1", -> it's a String
    keyword: "abcd", -> it's a String
    timestamp: " time1 " -> it's a Date()
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    keyword: "abcde",
    timestamp: " time2 "
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    keyword: "abcde",
    timestamp: " time3 "
  }
]
```

The code:

```swift
func getItemsByListTypeAndKeyword(listType: String, keyword: String = "", ascending: Bool = false) -> [[String: Any]]? {
    printIfDebug(instanceType: self, functionName: #function, id: id)
    
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "SearchHistoryItemModel")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \SearchHistoryItemModel.timestamp, ascending: ascending)
    ]
    if keyword.isEmpty {
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(
            format: "list.type = %@",
            listType
        )
    } else {
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(
            format: "(list.type = %@) AND (keyword beginswith %@)",
            listType,
            keyword
        )
    }
    
    fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [
        "keyword"
    ]
    
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
    
    let objects = try? viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    
    return objects?.compactMap({ item in
        print(item)
        return item as? [String: Any]
    })
}
```

Comment: Don’t use dictionaryResultType if you want all attributes. Fetch the whole object instead which is the default so actually don’t set resultType at all.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson without it, it will return duplicate `keyword` i.e. `book`, `book`, `cat`

Comment: Well what is really that you want to fetch? What is a distinct result? In your expected result sample you do have duplicate keywords.

Comment: I want to fetch both the `id`, and `keyword`. but i only want 1 distinct `keyword`. so if there is two data with exact keyword, i should only get the last one.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson right now I just fetch all then do filter manually. but i hope there is a better way since I use cloud kit and wish not to download unnecessary data.

Comment: You should update the question with those requirements so it becomes clearer.

Comment: how are you defining "last one"?

Comment: @flanker each item have property "keyword" and "timestamp", if there is an item with keyword "A" and timestamp Today and another item with keyword "A" and timestamp Today + 1. then it will only return the latter.